# Auto assigning 2 types of user roles on sign up in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to create a website that has two user roles primary and member. What i would like to happen is for by default a primary user to sign up and be assigned the primary role. When that primary user logs into the website, I would like them to have the ability to invite new users to the website. When that new user receives the invitation email and is redirected to the same sign up form, I would like that user to be auto assigned the member role on form submit. I have heard about the save method but not sure how to use it and what file it goes in. Would the process change if all users can potentially be both roles?

Comment: not as precise as it could be. if I want to anwser, I will need to read too much code that is probably not relevant...

Comment: @benzkji can you give any advice on the technique you would use to go about accomplishing, speaking in general.

Comment: accomplishing what exactly. auto assigning a role for example can be done in the save() method, assigning the default role for all new users, for example. but we dont have the form, neither do we know how you decide who has which role. please, re-read, and try to understand your own question, and remove non-relevant stuff, and add only the bare required, to understand your problem.

Comment: @benzkji thanks for your feedback. I re-worded my question and removed the code snippets so it caused less confusion. I did mention that I was new to Django so if there are more specifics you need from me that i am not aware of, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry but your problem is probably too broad. Answering it would mean to provide a more or less complete solution...SO is more about specific programming errors and things that do not work as expected. So I suggest you start with firing up your subscription form(s) (might check django-registrations...) and come back here when having concrete problem/errors.